# Setting JSON request header in Angular2 HTTP POST

Tags: http, typescript, angular, cors

I'm having a problem setting a content-type of application/json header on my post request.

```js
    saveUpdates(alltabs: AllTabs): Observable<Response> {
            let api = this.host + this.routes.save;
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return this._http.post(api, JSON.stringify(alltabs), { headers: headers })
            .map((response: Response) => <Response>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("saveUpdates(): " + data))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/productsave HTTP/1.1
Host: wbtest:92
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/product/60000010080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2016 15:16:15 GMT
Content-Length: 76
```

As you can see, my request has two unexpected headers added "Access-Control-Request-Headers" and "Access-Control-Request-Method". This seems to suggest an issue with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). However, the web.conf file on the API server has been working and the response headers states "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *".

Any idea what could be wrong?

UPDATE:

The above code is correct - the problem is with the Sever code not being configured to handle preflight requests. In my case, the .NET Web API 2 application was not configured to allow CORS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CORS, you have two kinds of requests. As a matter of fact, the CORS specification distinguishes two distinct use cases:

- **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.
- **Preflighted requests**. When the "simple requests" use case doesn't apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

It seems that your server isn't configured to support preflighted request. The reason for the 405 status code (405 Method Not Allowed).

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Comment: I think you're correct (Chrome does state "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP"), but adding "<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />" and "<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />" to my web.conf still gives the same issue.

Comment: I don't know what you use for your server but generally there are things to do. For example with Node, you need to define a middleware in Express to handle OPTIONS methods. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Thanks Thierry. It seems our .NET Web API 2 application was not configured to handle preflight requests.