# angular.js getting json not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i creat android app that work whit my site whit json api .but i have one problem in my browser;
my cod in app.js is:

```
$http.get('http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json')
.success(function(response){
  angular.forEach(response.data.children,function(child){

  $scope.stories.push(child.data);

  });
```

and this is my problem in chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   htttp://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.38:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. ?ionicplatform=ios:1

pleas help...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read about `CORS`.

This is a good [start for Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/).

It is recommended that you implement the solution in your backend.

Only for testing purpose you can use the `CORS` plugin in Chrome app store and enable it, to make the requests work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816437/2739864).

It explains about **simple CORS requests** and **preflight CORS request**s sent by angular, to obtain data.

Hope it helps you.